# Storing XML Element in MySql

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a bunch of XML files and I am using bash library: xsltproc to transform the XML file and then load them to a table.

The transformed XML file is flat:

```
<foos>
    <foo>
        <p>3. some random value.</p>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <p>3. The <h2>TOP LETTERS</h1>, this </p>
    </foo>
 <foo>threes</foo>
</foos>
```

When I do:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/home/dev/f/f.xml' INTO TABLE foo rows identified by '<foo>';
```

I get:

```
| id | foo    |
+----+--------+
|  1 | NULL   |
|  2 | NULL   |
|  3 | threes |
```

My goal is to make sure I store the whole text inside the `<foo>` element.

My table structure is as follows:

```
mysql> desc foo;                                                                                                
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                            │
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |                                            │
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                            │
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |                                            │
| foo   | mediumtext       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |                                            │
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to have the result as:

```
| id | foo    |
+----+--------+
|  1 | <p>3. The <h2>TOP LETTERS</h1>, this </p>   |
|  2 | <p>3. The <h2>TOP LETTERS</h1>, this </p>   |
|  3 | threes |
```

I have tried looking at different functions of mysql such as *ExtractValue* which extracts the text and strips the xml tags.

Comment: Where does the xml come from? It's invalid (`<h2>...</h1>`) which will probably confuse the reader.

Comment: No, i have tested it several ways. The XML element i am trying to store into the database is valid xml element.